# How to select a row in pageblock on click?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a pageblock table where in  I must be able to select one or multiple rows on clicking the row itself. On clicking a button, these rows must be displayed below the table in another table to show as selected. I am using a wrapper to display the records.
Can i have a checkbox kept hidden for the purpose. Is it possible to update the hidden checkbox on row select through javascript or jquery?

Comment: You can definitely add a row click listener in javascript. I don't think you need to worry about checkboxes at all, though you do need a way to track the row ids and probably send them back to the server.

Comment: I am new to javascript and jquery. My code will resemble something like below   

<script>
var lastRow;
function highlight(elem){
    elem.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';   
}
</script>

<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!list1}" var="item" rules="rows" id="myTable1" onRowClick="highlight(this);">
    <apex:column value="{!item.id}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>    
</apex:pageBlock>  

I need to show the highlighted rows in a separate table

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could do something like:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";
    $('body').on('click', 'tr.dataRow', function (event) {
        // do stuff
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I ended up building out a pretty complicated page using angular for my project with a similar feature, so most of the rest of my code would not apply to your situation. From here you will probably want to maintain (in JS) a collection of ids of record rows you have selected and send them back to the server with an actionFunction.